# Loop over hosts in serial with group in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

There are hosts inventory like this:

```
[cluster]
10.1.1.1 rack=1
10.1.1.2 rack=1
10.1.1.3 rack=1
10.1.1.4 rack=2
10.1.1.5 rack=2
.
.
10.1.1.150 rack=50
```

I want to restart each group of hosts that have same rack number in serial. that mean in first restart 3 server with rack number 1 and after these 3 server reachable restart next 3 server and continue.

is there any why to do this with ansible?

Comment: Not sure if "serial" accepts group vars. Have you tried it?